How do I fix the error "'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." when using SSMS Import Data Wizard
I'm running SSMS 20.1 and need to import an excel spreadsheet. I get an error message (see title). I tried installing the microsoft access database engine 16, 64 bit but the wizard still showed the same error. I can't install the 32 bit version because my version of MS office is 64 bit.
Seems the older install file is no longer available.
How can I get this data engine installed? Or is there another solution?

I think the fundamental problem is that SSMS, v 20.1, is a 32 bit application. SSMS Import Data wizard uses a 32 bit Access redistributable if you're going to import from an xlsx file.

I uninstalled my Microsoft Office (which was a 64 bit install). Then, I installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable 32 bit version enter link description here
At this point, I was able to run SSMS and get the Import Data wizard to import from an xlsx file. Finally, I re-installed Microsoft Office 365 (Default Version). Everything seems to work (well, except Access but I'll figure that out later).

I'm actually not thrilled with the solution. It does fix the issue with using the Import Data import wizard when importing an xlsx file but the 32 bit MS 365 install lacks some features that I really needed. I went back to the 64bit version of ssms and found an old version of AccessDatabaseEngine, 2010 and installed that.
